Apply partial reward point
I'm using Magento 2 EE version and implement the reward point. Currently, Magento will apply all of user point. I overrided the reward point block with an input for user to enter how many points he want to use. Then he will click a button to trigger an ajax. Here is my code so far:
            $.ajax({
                url: url.build('rest/default/V1/reward/mine/use-reward'),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify({ amount: rewardPoints }),
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('point', rewardPoints);
                    console.log('Response', response);
                    customerData.reload(['cart', 'checkout'], true);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.error('Fail to apply');
                }
            });

After I click the button, it log to console point, response = true. But it does not update the total amount. When I reload the page, it then show the deducted point, but the whole point of user.
Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much

can you please try the below code in your logic
$.ajax({
    url: url.build('rest/default/V1/reward/mine/use-reward'),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ amount: rewardPoints }),
    success: function (response) {
        console.log('Point Used:', rewardPoints);
        console.log('Response', response);
        
        // Reload cart/checkout sections
        customerData.reload(['cart', 'checkout'], true);

        // Update frontend totals manually if needed
        updateTotalsAndPoints(rewardPoints);
    },
    error: function () {
        console.error('Failed to apply points');
    }
});

function updateTotalsAndPoints(rewardPoints) {
    // Example: Find the reward points element and update it
    var rewardPointsElement = $('#reward-points-display');
    if (rewardPointsElement.length) {
        rewardPointsElement.text(rewardPoints);
    }

    // Similarly, you can update the total price with the deducted points
    // Fetch the current total, deduct the points, and update it
    var totalElement = $('#cart-total-price');
    var currentTotal = parseFloat(totalElement.text().replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
    var newTotal = currentTotal - rewardPoints;
    totalElement.text('$' + newTotal.toFixed(2));
}


Hi @patel, thank you for your response. It seems that your approach is to manually change text of deducted point, total amount. But I think these thing can be done automaticaly. I think the problem may be with that ajax endpoint. I don't know if I pass the correct parameter

Hi @patel. After dig deeper into this ajax endpoint, I see that it pnly help trigger deduct point when clicking the button. I see it take a parameter $cartId and then get current user information then deduct user's point. Totally not relating to user's input point. Guess I have to take another approach
